# AWT exception in thread with list

Tags: java, list, containers

i have a associationmodel class which is pretty easy:

```
package login;

import java.util.List;

public class AssociationModel {
    private String AssociationName;
    private List<UserModel> UserList;

public AssociationModel(String name){
    this.AssociationName = name;
}

public void RegisterUser(UserModel user){
    UserList.add(user);
}
public List<UserModel> getUsers(){
    return UserList;
}
public String getName(){
    return AssociationName;
}
}
```

Furthemore i have another class which has an java.util.list of AssociationModel´s

If i want to add AssociationModel´s to the AssociationList of the other class i get a stracktrace

```
        while (SearchAssociationsResult.next()){
            //AssociationList.add(new AssociationModel(SearchAssociationsResult.getString("ASSOCIATION_NAME")));
            AssociationModel l_association = new AssociationModel(SearchAssociationsResult.getString("ASSOCIATION_NAME"));
            AssociationList.add(l_association);
            System.out.println(l_association.getName());
        }




Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at login.AssociationController.CreateAssociations(AssociationController.java:35)
    at login.AssociationController.<init>(AssociationController.java:16)
    at login.LoginController.LoginAttempt(LoginController.java:48)
    at login.LoginView$1.actionPerformed(LoginView.java:52)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I am sure its a pretty stupid mistake...

Comment: AssociationList.add(l_association); This is the critical line

Comment: The import that you have is for awt list. change it to java util list. for AssociationList variable.

Comment: as you can see it is a java.util.list ...

Comment: It's not an AWT exception. It's just that the exception happens in the AWT dispatch thread. The exception is a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: This is clearly not an duplicate of a nullpointer exception question because if you check the code there is no nullpointer !!!!

Comment: Ah i got it the problem was that the list was not initialized with an arraylist